Tx sign: WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
I got the following .tsx code and when I trigger the tx it sucesfully prompts on phantom, however on accept, I get a console log error:
app-index.tsx:25 GOT ERROR Error: Unexpected error
    at Bi.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:235262)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at s (<anonymous>:1:1456) window.console.error @ app-index.tsx:25 console.error @ hydration-error-info.ts:72 overrideMethod @ console.js:273 (anonymous) @ VM75581:3 s @ VM75581:1 Promise.then (async) u @ VM75581:1 (anonymous) @ VM75581:1 He @ VM75581:1 (anonymous) @ VM75581:3 (anonymous) @ VM75581:3 (anonymous) @ VM75581:1 He @ VM75581:1 Ay.signAndSendTransaction @ VM75581:3 (anonymous) @ VM75581:3 (anonymous) @ VM75581:1 He @ VM75581:1 (anonymous) @ VM75581:3 sendTransaction @ adapter.js:171 await in sendTransaction (async) eval @ WalletProviderBase.js:152 initMaster @ UserContext.tsx:160 await in initMaster (async) callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:20565 invokeGuardedCallbackImpl @ react-dom.development.js:20614 invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:20689 invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:20703 executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:32128 processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:32160 processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:32173 dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:32184 eval @ react-dom.development.js:32374 batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24953 batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:28844 dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:32373 dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:30141 dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:30112 Show 1 more frame Show less app-index.tsx:25 WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
    at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.js:205:1)
    at async eval (WalletProviderBase.js:152:1)
    at async initMaster (UserContext.tsx:160:46) 

What might be causing this?
Here's my function call on frontend:

console.log("Master Address: " + masterAddress);
console.log("Payer: " + user?.wallet_address);
console.log("ProgramId: " + PROGRAM_ID);

let tx = new Transaction();
console.log("Tryinf rx");

const instructone: TransactionInstruction = await program.methods
    .initMaster()
    .accounts({
        master: masterAddress,
        payer: user?.wallet_address,
        systemProgram: PROGRAM_ID,
    })
    .instruction();

tx.add(instructone);
const transactionSignature = await sendTransaction(tx, connection);

console.log("tx signature: " + transactionSignature);

Idl/Types:
    "instructions": [
        {
          "name": "initMaster",
          "accounts": [
            {
              "name": "master",
              "isMut": true,
              "isSigner": false
            },
            {
              "name": "payer",
              "isMut": true,
              "isSigner": true
            },
            {
              "name": "systemProgram",
              "isMut": false,
              "isSigner": false
            }
          ],
          "args": []
        },

I am not sure if it's handling Phantom on my end or something on the tx itself



Is systemProgram: PROGRAM_ID, the system program ID - 11111111111111111111111111111111?
import { SystemProgram } from "@solana/web3.js";

const instructone: TransactionInstruction = await program.methods
    .initMaster()
    .accounts({
        master: masterAddress,
        payer: user?.wallet_address,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .instruction();


hello, my problem similar but i added systemProgram, error still occur

@HiderrKamado could you create a new question with your code.

I have a similar problem

code
const init = async (
    pda_nr: number,
    answer: number | string,
    theme: string,
    description: string,
    percent: number,
    bet: number,
    end: number,
  ) => {
    const assAcc = await getOrCreateAccount();
    const program: any = getProgram();
    const da_pda = await getDaPda(pda_nr);

    const connection = getConnection();

    const transaction = new Transaction();

    transaction.add(
      await program.methods
        .init(answer, theme, description, percent, bet, end, pda_nr)
        .accounts({
          dataAccount: da_pda,
          systemProgram: getSystemProgram(),
          user: wallet.publicKey,
          fromAta: assAcc.address.toBase58(),
          toAta: getToAta(),
          tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        })
        .instruction(),
    );

    return await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction, connection);
  };


Could you please open a new question.
